# Extract capture group only from string

Tags: regex

I have the following rule:

https://regex101.com/r/noX9lj/4

I want to make this work in a script so I'm using grep like this:

`echo "\$this->table('test')" | grep -Po "qr/\$this->table\(\'(test)\'\);/"`

The output should be "test"

It's not working, not sure why..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
 echo "\$this->table('test');" | grep -oP "\\\$this->table\\('\\K[^']+(?='\\);)"
```

Or, if you feed a file path to `grep`:

```
grep -oP "\\\$this->table\\('\\K[^']+(?='\\);)" file
```

See the [online `grep` demo](https://ideone.com/fvlzEk)

To match `$`, you need to escape it with a literal backslash, and inside a double quoted string, you need to escape `$` itself with one backslash char in order to stop variable expansion, and then you need to add two more backslashes to regex-escape the literal `$` char, hence is the `"\\\$"` in the pattern.

To match any text between two single quotes, you may use `[^']+` - 1 or more chars other than `'`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/maWMfg/1)

**Pattern details**

- `\$this->table\('` - `$this->table('` string
- `\K` - match reset operator that discards the text matched so far from the overall match buffer
- `[^']+` - one or more chars other than  `'`
- `(?='\);)` - a positive lookahead that requires `');` string to be present immediately to the right of the current position.

Comment: thank you for the explanation! i have one questions though.. i only have a basic understanding of regex but how come the regex works within the regex101 UI but when i use it in the terminal the same rule pattern doesn't work? @Wiktor Stribiżew

Comment: @AlexLatour Which pattern exactly? `\$this->table\(\'(test)\'\);`? You need to escape the regex special characters properly inside double quoted strings. `$` is also special in Bash, it also needs another escaping.

Comment: This one was my original one: https://regex101.com/r/noX9lj/6

Answer (score 1):

There were multiple issues:

1. had to use "cat" instead of echo for some reason
2. used this rule instead:

`grep -oP "this->table\('\K\w+(?='\);)"`